# How to convert snippets to asciidoc html in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

how to convert generated snippets to ASCII-doc html in spring boot.
i have already tried added the ASCII plugin.
i have already created .adoc file in src/main/asciidoc, but after maven build, it does not generate the html

```
include::{snippets}/test_find_by_id/http-request.adoc[]




          <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Documentation.java</include>
            </includes>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <org.springframework.restdocs.outputDir>
                    ${snippetsDirectory}
                </org.springframework.restdocs.outputDir>
            </systemPropertyVariables>   
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-docs</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
                <goals>
                    <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <backend>html</backend>
                    <doctype>book</doctype>
                    <attributes>
                        <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
                    </attributes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

<plugin> 
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>

    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
     <!--    <phase>process-resources</phase>--> 
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>   
        </goals>

        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
            </outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                    </directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the ASCII Doc Maven plugin in your pom.xml. See: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin#installation

Comment: i have already done that, adding the pom plugin above, as i am editing my answer.

Comment: Looks good. Have you tried running maven with the "process-asciidoc" goal? `mvn process-asciidoc`. If you are working from within Eclipse you can right click on the project, go to Run As, then Maven Build.. , then add the goal and click run

Comment: i am getting the following error.

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "process-asciidoc". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile,

Comment: you could try: `mvn org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:process-asciidoc` I built that from the plugin description in the pom

Comment: Thank you. it genertaed the docs, but it generated it in XML, where can i make it HTML

Comment: See https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin#usage. You need to change to ID of your execution to `output-html`

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn prepare-package
```

is the solution